# Querying dates in NSPredicate doesn't seem right: not able to match future dates

Tags: iphone, datetime, sqlite, core-data

I have some XML data retrieved from a web service that I use to create `NSManagedObject`s and store in a sqlite3 backing store.  In my app, I'm using `NSPredicate` objects to query this data by date (along with other fields).  The data I have has records for every day from April 2009 through August 2010 (according to the raw XML I retrieved from the SOAP web service).

Here's a little setup:

```
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

NSDate *today = [cal dateFromComponents:[cal components:NSDayCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit
                                               fromDate:[NSDate date]]];
NSDate *day1ahead = [cal dateFromComponents:[cal components:NSDayCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit
                                                   fromDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:kSecondsPerDay]]];
NSDate *day2ahead = [cal dateFromComponents:[cal components:NSDayCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit
                                                   fromDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNOw:kSecondsPerDay*2]]];
```

I am able successfully retrieve `NSManagedObject`s using an `NSPredicate` query like this:

```
NSPredicate *todaysData = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(StartDate >= %@) AND (StartDate <= %@)", today, day1ahead];
```

However, when I do a query like the next one, I get bupkis.

```
NSPredicate *tomorrowsData = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(StartDate >= %@) AND (StartDate <= %@)", day1ahead, day2ahead];
```

I checked the XML data, and the future dates for which I'm trying to query are there, and I also checked the sqlite3 backing store directly like this:

```
sqlite> select datetime(startdate, "unixepoch", "31 years") from mydatatable;
```

The results of this simple query show that the future dates I'm after are there.

I even tried a query like this:

```
NSPredicate *allFuture = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(StartDate >= %@)", today];
```

The results did not include anything beyond the current day.  It seems to be in the backing store, so I'm a bit at a loss as to why the NSPredicate objects aren't working the way I expect them to.

Is there a way to see the actual SQL statements generated by CoreData so I can see truly what's going on?  Am I looking at the data wrong in the sqlite3 db?  Is there something else obvious that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to see the actual SQL statements generated by CoreData so I can see truly what's going on?

Yes. In your Active Executable settings in Xcode, add `-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1` to the "Arguments to be passed on launch" list and check the checkmark. Core Data will then NSLog its SQL queries.

Comment: Thanks!  I actually figured out the problem was that I wasn't loading the right data in the array against which I was running my queries.  I was going to delete the question, but this is a good answer.